# Fancybox description box out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have this fancybox pop-up image with a description box. My problem is that when i re-size the browser from up to down (try it in the jsfiddle) the text seems to get out of the the box. Any idea on how to solve it?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/tqnk7e3f/

Code:
HTML:

```
<a caption="<h2>Image Header</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>" rel="Sold" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.fancybox-title {
    right:auto;
    height:100%;
    left:-260px;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}

.fancybox-title .child {
    height:100%;
    white-space:normal;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 20px;
    max-width:200px;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-radius:0;
}

.fancybox-title .child h2 {
    font-size:140%;
    line-height:1.5;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.fancybox-title .child p {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
     $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'fade',
                nextEffect : 'fade',
               padding:0,

                closeBtn  : true,
                arrows    : true,

               nextClick : true,    


               helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'outside' }
   },

               helpers : {

                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 80,
                        height : 80

                    }
                },



 beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
   }

            });
```

Comment: how about something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/tqnk7e3f/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem well i suggest to change property of `.fancybox-title` from `height:100%` to `height:auto`. With response design it's always better for me to use **auto height**.
check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqnk7e3f/1/) !
Let me know if it helps!

**EDIT**

So here's new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqnk7e3f/3/).

i updated few things :

```
 top: 0;
```

against `bottom:0`

and leave `height:auto` as it was in my previous example.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.fancybox-title {
    right:auto;
    height:auto;
    left:-260px;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    /* CHANGES */
    top: 0;
}

.fancybox-title .child {
    height: auto;
    white-space:normal;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 20px;
    max-width:200px;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-radius:0;
}

.fancybox-title .child h2 {
    font-size:140%;
    line-height:1.5;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.fancybox-title .child p {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Wainting again for your check :)

Comment: yeah it's what i want, however the description box must have the same height and width as in the original jsfiddle. Can it be done?

Comment: Please check out my post **EDIT** ;)

Comment: @ Raźnyy if you had time or logged in today please check this follow-up question for this problem   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042106/fancybox-description-box-maintaining-size-upon-window-re-size